# How to make a single .a file (static library) using many .cpp routines?

Tags: gcc, g++, static-libraries

I have a directory "rec" full of .cpp routines and I want to make a "rec.a" file so that I can use the routines while compiling my test.cpp program. How to do this? I am using g++.

Answer (score 0):

Compile the source into object files (.o) then use the command `ar`:

```
> ar -rsc libfoo.a objfoo.o
```

Comment: I could not find the link. Can you please elaborate? What are the steps? I am a beginner.

Comment: Sorry. I don't know why the link didn't work. Here is a tutorial: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/gcc/create_lib.html

Comment: These are command line utilities, but I assume that is what you want if you are using gcc or g++.

Comment: How do I feed all the .cpp routines? I am not following. Do I really need library file? Or something else?

Comment: You have to compile all the .cpp files into .o files with g++. Then when you bundle them into the archive, you simply write the rule: `> ar -rsc libfoo.a file1.o file2.o ...filen.o`. the command `ar` takes .o files (compiled source code) and puts them into a single container -- a library -- that you can link to in the standard ways.

Comment: Also you probably want to familiarize yourself with makefiles and the make command. There is a pretty comprehensive tutorial here: http://viralpatel.net/taj/tutorial/makefile-tutorial.php

Comment: That is impossible, because I have hundreds of .cpp routines. Do I really need library file? Or something else? Somebody made such a .a file for me and it does not start with "lib", works fine. Now I modified the .cpp routines, hence need to make the .a again.

Comment: Ok, so first of all, obviously if you modify your code, you have to recompile it to reflect the changes. Makefiles are nice, because once you get it set up, you just have to type `make` and all the steps are automated. How many files are your cpp 'routines' in? You can always copy and paste them all into one file so that you don't have to type a lot at the command line.

Comment: may be 500 .cpp routines are there. Impossible to copy all of them.

Comment: So what to do? Is there a way out?

Comment: As I said before, a makefile can help you with this. Look at some examples, read the tutorial (this is how we learn to code). You will probably have to type the names of all your .cpp files in the rec folder into your makefil, but only once. You can also write a shell script that will print the names of every file in the directory into a text file -- but that may take you longer to figure out how to do than actually typing them in one by one. Good luck.